# RPM Build error : D: May free Score board((nil))

Tags: linux, fedora, package-management, packaging, rpm

I have a problem building , it fails with the error:

D: May free Score board((nil))

What does this mean ? I do not see any other errors appearing in the build before this so i am fairly stumped by the lack of information.

OS : FC 8

Edit : FYI , it builds fine on FC10,13.

Edit2 : Sorry for the missing info guys. I am trying to build a soap engine from apache - Axis2c. I am creating an RPM for the same. Here are the details of the spec file.

```
define _axis_name axis2-c
%define _axis_version 1.0
%define _axis_release 1
%define _axis_prefix "/usr/local/Axis2C"


Name:           %{_axis_name}
Version:        %{_axis_version}
Release:        %{_axis_release}
Summary:        Axis2C C++ Webservices Framework

Group:          Apache
License:        GPL
URL:            http://axis.apache.org/axis2/c/core/
Source0:        %{_axis_name}-%{_axis_version}.tar.gz
BuildRoot:      %(mktemp -ud %{_tmppath}/%{name}-%{version}-%{release}-XXXXXX)

BuildRequires:  expat expat-devel xerces-c xerces-c-devel httpd httpd-devel
Requires:       expat expat-devel xerces-c xerces-c-devel httpd httpd-devel

%description
* Fri Jan 21 2011 RM<xx@xxx>
- First Attempt to build Axis2C RPM's

%prep
%setup -q


%build
#%configure
#make %{?_smp_mflags}
%define AXISHOME %(echo ${AXIS2C_HOME})
./build.sh



%install
rm -rf $RPM_BUILD_ROOT
make install DESTDIR=$RPM_BUILD_ROOT
mkdir -p ${RPM_BUILD_ROOT}/etc/ld.so.conf.d
cp ${RPM_BUILD_DIR}/${RPM_PACKAGE_NAME}-${RPM_PACKAGE_VERSION}/axis2c.conf ${RPM_BUILD_ROOT}/etc/ld.so.conf.d/axis2c.conf

%clean
rm -rf $RPM_BUILD_ROOT


%files
%defattr(-,root,root,-)
%doc
/etc/ld.so.conf.d/axis2c.conf
%{AXISHOME}/AUTHORS
%{AXISHOME}/COPYING
%{AXISHOME}/CREDITS
%{AXISHOME}/INSTALL
%{AXISHOME}/LICENSE
%{AXISHOME}/NEWS
%{AXISHOME}/NOTICE
%{AXISHOME}/axis2.xml
%{AXISHOME}/bin/axis2_http_server
.......
```

Build :

```
rpmbuild -bs --nodeps /root/rpmbuild/SPECS/axis2c.spec
rpmbuild -vv --rebuild --target "i686" /root/rpmbuild/SRPMS/axis2-c-1.0-1.src.rpm
```

Comment: What are you building and what command are you using?

Comment: Your question is unanswerable as it is. You need to say what you are trying to build, and copy-paste both the exact command you're using for building and the full output from the build process.

Comment: @Tshepang & @Gilles : I hope the info provides what you guys required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error "D: May free Score board((nil))" is most likely not a useful diagnostic error, it just is the last line in the verbose output.